# Solving first order ODE with a transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the ODE:

> $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x} + e^{\frac{y}{x}}$

I have a solution that says we can use a transformation $ z = \frac{y}{x}$. This would give:

$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{e^Z}{x}$

How can we get this expression with $\frac{dz}{dx}$ from $\frac{dy}{dx}$? I don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing this:

$$  z=\frac{y}{x} = yx^{-1} \ \implies \frac{dz}{dx} = -x^{-2}y + x^{-1}\frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$ x\frac{dz}{dx} + z= \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Now substitute $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in the original equation:

$$x\frac{dz}{dx} = e^{z} $$

$$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{e^z}{x}$$

The aim is to transform the differential equation into one containing the variables $z$ and $x$ (in place of $x$ and $y$). Its helpful to know a little about [implicit differentiation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sL6MC-lKOrw) for this type of problem.